# Enable/Disable Windows Key

Tags: c#, windows

I use the following code for Enable/Disable windows key in Keyboard.It was working fine .

```
    public static class WindowsKey {
              public static void Disable() {
            RegistryKey key = null;
            try {
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Keyboard Layout", true);
                byte[] binary = new byte[] { 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x03, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x5B, 
                    0xE0, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x5C, 
                    0xE0, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00 
                };
                key.SetValue("Scancode Map", binary, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) {
                Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());
            }
            finally {
                key.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void Enable() {
            RegistryKey key = null;
            try {
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Keyboard Layout", true);
                key.DeleteValue("Scancode Map", true);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) {
                Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString());
            }
            finally {
                key.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

But If I use the above code it was affect enable/disable after the System getting Restarted.

I need to do with this on Button click from C#.Which means If I call the Disable function from the above code I need to disable windows key Immediately(not affect After Restart).

If I call Enable function from the above code in Button click I need to Enable Windows Key.

How can I do this?? Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: In a Windows Forms Application?

Comment: There is a sample code showing, how to and Interrupt keys, I think I used it in the past: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0071e0ab-39ee-4093-8cca-2560fae002f9/how-to-disable-windows-key-in-keydown-event-for-a-windows-form?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a page: [Disabling Shortcut Keys in Games](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416808(v=vs.85).aspx), which sounds like what you need.

Essentially you install a low-level keyboard hook to eat the undesired keys. You also need to handle the `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message to enable/disable the hook appropriately (otherwise you'll eat the keys when you're not the active application).

Here's [an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) of installing a low-level keyboard hook from C#.