# Re-Enable Windows key from Disable Windows key class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi thanks for taking your time to read. My problem is i have created a class file with some help from researching and found code that disables my windows key and i have implemented this code into a checkbox value if true. Once the checkbox has been checked it runs the class file i have created but i need to disable this code to enable the Windows key again once i uncheck the checkbox. I admit this code is above my head a little and i have gone through this code multiple times and still trying to figure out how it is structured and works.

```
class EnableDisableKeys
{
    // Structure contain information about low-level keyboard input event
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr extra;
    }

    //System level functions to be used for hook and unhook keyboard input
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);


    //Declaring Global objects
    private IntPtr ptrHook;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

    public void KeyHook()
    {
        ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
        objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(captureKey);
        ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }

    private IntPtr captureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin) // Disabling Windows keys
            {
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
    }


}
```

And on my Winform.

```
public partial class ParentalSettingsForm : Form
{
    EnableDisableKeys ed = new EnableDisableKeys();
    public ParentalSettingsForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ParentalSettingsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBoxDisableWindowsKey_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBoxDisableWindowsKey.Checked == true)
        {
            ed.KeyHook();
        }

    }
}
```

Now i know its probably a minor setting i need to change somewhere to disable but cannot seem to find it. Until i get an answer i will continue to work on this solution but like i have mentioned anything to do with disabling or re-enabling keys is completly new to me. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this would be a better solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516128/enable-disable-windows-key

Comment: Thanks for the reply i have already looked at this solution but it requires a system restart for it to take place and i dont want that. If its possible to disable the Win key within this code it has to be possible to re-enable but thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Setup a boolean flag in your class to tell it whether to suppress the win key or not.  Check it in your captureKey() method.  Here I've set the default to suppress the key:

```
    public bool SuppressWinKey = true;

    private IntPtr captureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin) // Disabling Windows keys
            {
                if (SuppressWinKey)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1;
                }
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
    }
```

In your form, setup the hook when the form loads (not in response to the checkbox):

```
EnableDisableKeys ed = new EnableDisableKeys();

private void ParentalSettingsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ed.KeyHook();
}
```

Now toggle that flag when the checkbox is changed:

```
private void checkBoxDisableWindowsKey_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ed.SuppressWinKey = checkBoxDisableWindowsKey.Checked;
}
```